# What methods can be used to stabilize a vibratory bowl used for orientation

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, vibration, building-design, plastic, machine-design

I have a project where we are using a vibratory bowl to feed in parts to an assembler. The issue I am having is that the calibration sticker on the side is very out and a single line is very difficult to even get.

The issue comes from the base which is elevated. This needs to become more rigid within the machine however I am having difficulty finding solutions for this.

Please could you help with some options that may work.

Comment: You want to stabilze a vibrating bowl? From overturning or moving millimetres?

Comment: @SolarMike I want to stabilize the bowl so that I can achieve the correct motion and be able to get a straight line on the calibration sticker. The orientation differs when it is on this stand compared to when I place it on say, a table or the floor. This causes some of the parts to be fed in upside down.

Comment: Maybe add mass between the bowl and the stand to change its resonant frequency?

Comment: I assume you already know it's not a problem with the springs?  I've never actually tuned one of these.  Making the base stiffer would usually mean adding angle iron to the support base.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is a "calibration sticker" in the context of vibratory bowl feeding? What gets calibrated? Frequency? Amplitude? Alignment?

Comment: To reply to the community bot message, what I need assistance with is stabilizing the bowl so that the amplitude of the vibrations can be adjusted so that the correct movement inside the bowl can be achieved.

Comment: @Transistor The calibration sticker is what's used to "set" the bowl. One the bowl is correctly stabilized, as I understand, the calibration sticker which is two lines converges into one due to the frequency of the vibrations when viewed with a human eye

Comment: @TigerGuy I've checked, the springs are okay. Hmm, yes angle Iron would actually be a good idea, I will try this.